# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION while calling IBM ILOG CPLEX

Tags: java, fatal-error, cplex

I'm calling IBM ILOG CPLEX multiple times from one object in Java.

After a few 100-1000 calls the program crashes. I have attached the text of the log file below.

Does anybody have a clue what may be the problem? Thank you!

---

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000076d50901, pid=6780, tid=6796

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [ntdll.dll+0x50901]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

- T H R E A D -

Current thread (0x000000001d57c000):  JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=6796, stack(0x000000001f4d0000,0x000000001f5d0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000005590dc0568

Registers:
RAX=0x00000000238ff010, RBX=0x0000005590dc0560, RCX=0x000000ffffffffff, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000001f5cf640, RBP=0x00000000216953d0, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x00000000216953c0, R9 =0x0000000000000700, R10=0x0000000000004a89, R11=0x000000001f5cf7b0
R12=0x0000000002330000, R13=0x0000000071ddac40, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x0000000071ddacd0
RIP=0x0000000076d50901, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001f5cf640)
0x000000001f5cf640:   0000000100000000 0006754d0000001d
0x000000001f5cf650:   ffffffffff644000 000000001f5cf660
0x000000001f5cf660:   0000060100000000 0300000000000300
0x000000001f5cf670:   000000001d56b53a 000000006380e62c
0x000000001f5cf680:   0000000071ddacd0 0000000000000000
0x000000001f5cf690:   0000000000000000 000000000233aad0
0x000000001f5cf6a0:   00000000216953d0 000000001d57c1e8
0x000000001f5cf6b0:   000000001d57c000 0000000076b01a7a
0x000000001f5cf6c0:   000000001d578600 0000000071ddac40
0x000000001f5cf6d0:   000000001d568340 0000000000000000
0x000000001f5cf6e0:   0000000000000000 0000000063f28d94
0x000000001f5cf6f0:   000000001d55ee00 000000001d568340
0x000000001f5cf700:   0000000000000000 000000001d57c000
0x000000001f5cf710:   000000001d57c000 00000000637f1c49
0x000000001f5cf720:   000000001d57c000 0000000000000004
0x000000001f5cf730:   000000001d568340 000000001d57c000 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000076d50901)
0x0000000076d508e1:   ff ff 00 00 00 49 33 dc 48 23 c1 48 c1 eb 04 48
0x0000000076d508f1:   33 d8 48 33 1d ce ea 0d 00 48 c1 e3 04 0f 0d 0b
0x0000000076d50901:   48 8b 7b 08 49 bd 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 49 be
0x0000000076d50911:   ff 7f 00 00 ff ff ff ff 41 c6 40 0f 80 41 88 70 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000000238ff010 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000005590dc0560 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000ffffffffff is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001f5cf640 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001d57c000
RBP=0x00000000216953d0 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00000000216953c0 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000700 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000004a89 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000001f5cf7b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001d57c000
R12=0x0000000002330000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000071ddac40 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000071ddacd0 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x000000001f4d0000,0x000000001f5d0000],  sp=0x000000001f5cf640,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x50901]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x21a7a]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x68d94]
V  [jvm.dll+0x191c49]
V  [jvm.dll+0x317866]
C  [jdwp.dll+0x22912]
C  [jdwp.dll+0x1673a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1abba8]
V  [jvm.dll+0x22bde4]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2852fa]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x21d9f]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x21e3b]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x159ed]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2b371]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000001d60c800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5732, stack(0x000000001f960000,0x000000001fa60000)]
  0x000000001d5af800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6304, stack(0x000000001fcc0000,0x000000001fdc0000)]
  0x000000001d595000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5720, stack(0x000000001f3c0000,0x000000001f4c0000)]
  0x000000001d594000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3584, stack(0x000000001fa80000,0x000000001fb80000)]
  0x000000001d589800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4748, stack(0x000000001f840000,0x000000001f940000)]
  0x000000001d57f000 JavaThread "JDWP Command Reader" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5056, stack(0x000000001f690000,0x000000001f790000)]
=>0x000000001d57c000 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=6796, stack(0x000000001f4d0000,0x000000001f5d0000)]
  0x000000001d56f000 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3012, stack(0x000000001f140000,0x000000001f240000)]
  0x000000001d561000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6160, stack(0x000000001e490000,0x000000001e590000)]
  0x000000001d560000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4660, stack(0x000000001ea60000,0x000000001eb60000)]
  0x000000000243f000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5076, stack(0x000000001e8d0000,0x000000001e9d0000)]
  0x000000001c5b4800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1448, stack(0x000000001e710000,0x000000001e810000)]
  0x000000000233e800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=6072, stack(0x00000000026e0000,0x00000000027e0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000001c5af800 VMThread [stack: 0x000000001e600000,0x000000001e700000] [id=6964]
  0x000000001d60e800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000001fb80000,0x000000001fc80000] [id=6004]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 1112576K, used 757551K [0x000000076c500000, 0x00000007bfd80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1112064K, 68% used [0x000000076c500000,0x000000079a87be68,0x00000007b0300000)
  from space 512K, 62% used [0x00000007bfd00000,0x00000007bfd50000,0x00000007bfd80000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bfb80000,0x00000007bfb80000,0x00000007bfc80000)
 ParOldGen       total 75776K, used 62875K [0x00000006c4e00000, 0x00000006c9800000, 0x000000076c500000)
  object space 75776K, 82% used [0x00000006c4e00000,0x00000006c8b66f40,0x00000006c9800000)
 Metaspace       used 5493K, capacity 6124K, committed 6272K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 565K, capacity 596K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011e70000,0x0000000012650000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000e849000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000063e3d490
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000013660000, 0x0000000017528000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000017528000, 0x000000001b3f0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000140000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=5351Kb max_used=5926Kb free=240408Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002ab0000, 0x0000000003090000, 0x0000000011ab0000]
 total_blobs=1337 nmethods=927 adapters=332
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 696.991 Thread 0x000000001d589800 1236       4       interact.Assign$3::<init> (10 bytes)
Event: 696.992 Thread 0x000000001d589800 nmethod 1236 0x0000000002f7e010 code [0x0000000002f7e140, 0x0000000002f7e1b8]
Event: 771.706 Thread 0x000000001d594000 1237       4       java.util.Arrays::sort (37 bytes)
Event: 771.707 Thread 0x000000001d594000 nmethod 1237 0x0000000002e8f010 code [0x0000000002e8f160, 0x0000000002e8f228]
Event: 901.169 Thread 0x000000001d5af800 1238       3       java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::get (162 bytes)
Event: 901.169 Thread 0x000000001d5af800 nmethod 1238 0x0000000002d3ea90 code [0x0000000002d3eca0, 0x0000000002d3f898]
Event: 1050.562 Thread 0x000000001d5af800 1239       3       java.lang.ref.SoftReference::get (29 bytes)
Event: 1050.562 Thread 0x000000001d5af800 nmethod 1239 0x0000000002ceaad0 code [0x0000000002ceac20, 0x0000000002ceae10]
Event: 1606.274 Thread 0x000000001d595000 1240       4       java.util.TimSort::mergeLo (659 bytes)
Event: 1606.314 Thread 0x000000001d595000 nmethod 1240 0x0000000002eb6d10 code [0x0000000002eb6f00, 0x0000000002eb9c58]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 1769.689 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7094 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1128448K, used 1127728K [0x000000076c500000, 0x00000007bff00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1127424K, 100% used [0x000000076c500000,0x00000007b1200000,0x00000007b1200000)
  from space 1024K, 29% used [0x00000007bfd00000,0x00000007bfd4c010,0x00000007bfe00000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bfe00000,0x00000007bfe00000,0x00000007bff00000)
 ParOldGen       total 75776K, used 62763K [0x00000006c4e00000, 0x00000006c9800000, 0x000000076c500000)
  object space 75776K, 82% used [0x00000006c4e00000,0x00000006c8b4af40,0x00000006c9800000)
 Metaspace       used 5493K, capacity 6124K, committed 6272K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 565K, capacity 596K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1769.693 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7094 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1350144K, used 432K [0x000000076c500000, 0x00000007bfe80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1349632K, 0% used [0x000000076c500000,0x000000076c500000,0x00000007beb00000)
  from space 512K, 84% used [0x00000007bfe00000,0x00000007bfe6c010,0x00000007bfe80000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bfc80000,0x00000007bfc80000,0x00000007bfd80000)
 ParOldGen       total 75776K, used 62779K [0x00000006c4e00000, 0x00000006c9800000, 0x000000076c500000)
  object space 75776K, 82% used [0x00000006c4e00000,0x00000006c8b4ef40,0x00000006c9800000)
 Metaspace       used 5493K, capacity 6124K, committed 6272K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 565K, capacity 596K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1770.041 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7095 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1350144K, used 1350064K [0x000000076c500000, 0x00000007bfe80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1349632K, 100% used [0x000000076c500000,0x00000007beb00000,0x00000007beb00000)
  from space 512K, 84% used [0x00000007bfe00000,0x00000007bfe6c010,0x00000007bfe80000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bfc80000,0x00000007bfc80000,0x00000007bfd80000)
 ParOldGen       total 75776K, used 62779K [0x00000006c4e00000, 0x00000006c9800000, 0x000000076c500000)
  object space 75776K, 82% used [0x00000006c4e00000,0x00000006c8b4ef40,0x00000006c9800000)
 Metaspace       used 5493K, capacity 6124K, committed 6272K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 565K, capacity 596K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1770.042 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7095 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1286656K, used 480K [0x000000076c500000, 0x00000007bfe80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1285632K, 0% used [0x000000076c500000,0x000000076c500000,0x00000007bac80000)
  from space 1024K, 46% used [0x00000007bfc80000,0x00000007bfcf8000,0x00000007bfd80000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bfd80000,0x00000007bfd80000,0x00000007bfe80000)
 ParOldGen       total 75776K, used 62811K [0x00000006c4e00000, 0x00000006c9800000, 0x000000076c500000)
  object space 75776K, 82% used [0x00000006c4e00000,0x00000006c8b56f40,0x00000006c9800000)
 Metaspace       used 5493K, capacity 6124K, committed 6272K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 565K, capacity 596K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1770.646 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7096 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1286656K, used 1286112K [0x000000076c500000, 0x00000007bfe80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1285632K, 100% used [0x000000076c500000,0x00000007bac80000,0x00000007bac80000)
  from space 1024K, 46% used [0x00000007bfc80000,0x00000007bfcf8000,0x00000007bfd80000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bfd80000,0x00000007bfd80000,0x00000007bfe80000)
 ParOldGen       total 75776K, used 62811K [0x00000006c4e00000, 0x00000006c9800000, 0x000000076c500000)
  object space 75776K, 82% used [0x00000006c4e00000,0x00000006c8b56f40,0x00000006c9800000)
 Metaspace       used 5493K, capacity 6124K, committed 6272K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 565K, capacity 596K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1770.647 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7096 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1225216K, used 448K [0x000000076c500000, 0x00000007bfe00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1224704K, 0% used [0x000000076c500000,0x000000076c500000,0x00000007b7100000)
  from space 512K, 87% used [0x00000007bfd80000,0x00000007bfdf0000,0x00000007bfe00000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bfc00000,0x00000007bfc00000,0x00000007bfd00000)
 ParOldGen       total 75776K, used 62835K [0x00000006c4e00000, 0x00000006c9800000, 0x000000076c500000)
  object space 75776K, 82% used [0x00000006c4e00000,0x00000006c8b5cf40,0x00000006c9800000)
 Metaspace       used 5493K, capacity 6124K, committed 6272K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 565K, capacity 596K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1770.939 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7097 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1225216K, used 1225152K [0x000000076c500000, 0x00000007bfe00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1224704K, 100% used [0x000000076c500000,0x00000007b7100000,0x00000007b7100000)
  from space 512K, 87% used [0x00000007bfd80000,0x00000007bfdf0000,0x00000007bfe00000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bfc00000,0x00000007bfc00000,0x00000007bfd00000)
 ParOldGen       total 75776K, used 62835K [0x00000006c4e00000, 0x00000006c9800000, 0x000000076c500000)
  object space 75776K, 82% used [0x00000006c4e00000,0x00000006c8b5cf40,0x00000006c9800000)
 Metaspace       used 5493K, capacity 6124K, committed 6272K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 565K, capacity 596K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1770.942 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7097 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1167872K, used 352K [0x000000076c500000, 0x00000007bfe00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1166848K, 0% used [0x000000076c500000,0x000000076c500000,0x00000007b3880000)
  from space 1024K, 34% used [0x00000007bfc00000,0x00000007bfc58000,0x00000007bfd00000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bfd00000,0x00000007bfd00000,0x00000007bfe00000)
 ParOldGen       total 75776K, used 62851K [0x00000006c4e00000, 0x00000006c9800000, 0x000000076c500000)
  object space 75776K, 82% used [0x00000006c4e00000,0x00000006c8b60f40,0x00000006c9800000)
 Metaspace       used 5493K, capacity 6124K, committed 6272K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 565K, capacity 596K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1771.282 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7098 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1167872K, used 1167200K [0x000000076c500000, 0x00000007bfe00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1166848K, 100% used [0x000000076c500000,0x00000007b3880000,0x00000007b3880000)
  from space 1024K, 34% used [0x00000007bfc00000,0x00000007bfc58000,0x00000007bfd00000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bfd00000,0x00000007bfd00000,0x00000007bfe00000)
 ParOldGen       total 75776K, used 62851K [0x00000006c4e00000, 0x00000006c9800000, 0x000000076c500000)
  object space 75776K, 82% used [0x00000006c4e00000,0x00000006c8b60f40,0x00000006c9800000)
 Metaspace       used 5493K, capacity 6124K, committed 6272K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 565K, capacity 596K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1771.283 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7098 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1112576K, used 320K [0x000000076c500000, 0x00000007bfd80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1112064K, 0% used [0x000000076c500000,0x000000076c500000,0x00000007b0300000)
  from space 512K, 62% used [0x00000007bfd00000,0x00000007bfd50000,0x00000007bfd80000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007bfb80000,0x00000007bfb80000,0x00000007bfc80000)
 ParOldGen       total 75776K, used 62875K [0x00000006c4e00000, 0x00000006c9800000, 0x000000076c500000)
  object space 75776K, 82% used [0x00000006c4e00000,0x00000006c8b66f40,0x00000006c9800000)
 Metaspace       used 5493K, capacity 6124K, committed 6272K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 565K, capacity 596K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 547.851 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002e9064c method=java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 282
Event: 547.919 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002e9064c method=java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 282
Event: 549.401 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002e340e4 method=java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 419
Event: 549.471 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002e340e4 method=java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 419
Event: 560.352 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002e305a4 method=java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 524
Event: 560.422 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002e305a4 method=java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 524
Event: 560.892 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002e2c5dc method=java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 657
Event: 560.957 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002e2c5dc method=java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 657
Event: 1600.066 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002db9c74 method=java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(IIII)V @ 133
Event: 1603.488 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002db9c74 method=java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(IIII)V @ 133

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 309.844 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076f698720) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 309.845 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076f69bf58) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 309.846 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076f69e928) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 309.856 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076fad6c68) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 309.856 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076fadbfb0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 309.877 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076fb08098) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 309.877 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076fb083e0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 309.877 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076fb0c308) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 309.878 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076fb0c650) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 309.982 Thread 0x000000000233e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x0000000773cd5b98) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]

Events (10 events):
Event: 1771.478 Thread 0x000000001ffd3000 Thread added: 0x000000001ffd3000
Event: 1771.478 Thread 0x0000000020fab000 Thread added: 0x0000000020fab000
Event: 1771.479 Thread 0x000000001ffd3000 Thread exited: 0x000000001ffd3000
Event: 1771.479 Thread 0x0000000020fab000 Thread exited: 0x0000000020fab000
Event: 1771.485 Thread 0x000000001ffd3000 Thread added: 0x000000001ffd3000
Event: 1771.485 Thread 0x0000000020fab000 Thread added: 0x0000000020fab000
Event: 1771.486 Thread 0x0000000020fab000 Thread exited: 0x0000000020fab000
Event: 1771.487 Thread 0x000000001ffd3000 Thread exited: 0x000000001ffd3000
Event: 1771.491 Thread 0x0000000020fab000 Thread added: 0x0000000020fab000
Event: 1771.491 Thread 0x000000001ffd3000 Thread added: 0x000000001ffd3000


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f170000 - 0x000000013f1a4000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
0x0000000076d00000 - 0x0000000076eaa000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076ae0000 - 0x0000000076bff000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefcaa0000 - 0x000007fefcb0b000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefce40000 - 0x000007fefcf1b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefeaa0000 - 0x000007fefeb3f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefec20000 - 0x000007fefec3f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefec40000 - 0x000007fefed6d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000076c00000 - 0x0000000076cfa000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefea30000 - 0x000007fefea97000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefda40000 - 0x000007fefda4e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefd510000 - 0x000007fefd5da000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefb470000 - 0x000007fefb664000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefd8f0000 - 0x000007fefd961000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefd970000 - 0x000007fefd99e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefef00000 - 0x000007feff009000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x00000000747e0000 - 0x0000000074818000     C:\PROGRA~2\Sophos\SOPHOS~1\SOPHOS~2.DLL
0x0000000076ec0000 - 0x0000000076ec7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000063ec0000 - 0x0000000063f92000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000063660000 - 0x0000000063eba000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef58e0000 - 0x000007fef58e9000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefd130000 - 0x000007fefd17d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefdc90000 - 0x000007fefdc98000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefa520000 - 0x000007fefa55b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x00000000724e0000 - 0x00000000724ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00000000724b0000 - 0x00000000724d8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000071db0000 - 0x0000000071de5000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\jdwp.dll
0x00000000724f0000 - 0x00000000724f8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\npt.dll
0x0000000072490000 - 0x00000000724a6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefdca0000 - 0x000007fefea2a000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefcf20000 - 0x000007fefd123000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefca80000 - 0x000007fefca8f000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x0000000071da0000 - 0x0000000071da9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\dt_socket.dll
0x000007fefa170000 - 0x000007fefa185000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef7430000 - 0x000007fef7445000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fef7450000 - 0x000007fef7469000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fefc1b0000 - 0x000007fefc205000     C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefc2f0000 - 0x000007fefc34b000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fef7010000 - 0x000007fef701b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fefb960000 - 0x000007fefb987000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefbc00000 - 0x000007fefbc0b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef98b0000 - 0x000007fef9903000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000007fef8c70000 - 0x000007fef8c78000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefbdc0000 - 0x000007fefbded000     C:\ProgramData\Sophos\Web Intelligence\swi_ifslsp_64.dll
0x000007fefbc10000 - 0x000007fefbc1c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x000007fefbbf0000 - 0x000007fefbbf7000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fee88c0000 - 0x000007fee9ea6000     C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1262\opl\bin\x64_win64\cplex1262remotejni.dll
0x000007fef07c0000 - 0x000007fef08e5000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:52567 -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: program.Main
java_class_path (initial): C:\Git\Code_Jonathan\workspace\TRAP\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1262\cplex\lib\cplex.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_73/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_73/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_73/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1262\opl\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1262\opl\oplide\;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1262\cplex\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1262\cpoptimizer\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\opl\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\opl\oplide\;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\cplex\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\cpoptimizer\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\opl\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\opl\oplide\;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\cplex\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\cpoptimizer\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\opl\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\opl\oplide\;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\cplex\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\cpoptimizer\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32;C:\Program Files\eclipse;
USERNAME=Jacob Jonathan
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



-  S Y S T E M  -

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 16453744k(7188540k free), swap 32905652k(23568488k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_25-b18), built on Oct  7 2014 14:25:37 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Wed Apr 13 12:04:39 2016
elapsed time: 1771 seconds (0d 0h 29m 31s)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "few 100-1000 calls"? is it a number of iterations or a number of the whole program consequtive calls? It might be better to submit a bug report to IBM directly.

Comment: I'm solving different instances of a set covering problem in a loop. To that end I am using only one instance of a class. I change the instance parameters of this class over which I am solving a set covering problem by means of a setter and then solve it. After a few hundred to thousand iterations, the crash happens. A simplified version of my code looks like this.

`this.scp = new SetCovering();
while (counter++ < max){
 change(parameters);
 scp.setSetCovering(parameters);
 scp.run;
}`

Comment: This may not help, but have you tried running with the [DataCheck](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/DataCheck.html) parameter turned on?

Comment: No I haven't yet. My constructor of the SetCovering() class now looks like this:
  `public SetCovering() throws IloException{
  this.cplex = new IloCplex();
  this.cplex.setParam(IloCplex.Param.Read.DataCheck, true);
 }` . Am I doing that right? Also I read somewhere considering a somewhat similar error message that running the program in release mode instead of debug mode may help. I will try that too.

Answer (score 0):

So, after letting the program run successfully in an infinite loop for the weekend, I can conclude that the problem was debug mode. Ironically, this is a bug that only appears when debugging but not in release mode. Whatever the cause may be, I'm fine with it now. Hope that will help some one sometime.

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you fix this?

Comment: I did not really get more insights into this. Release mode instead of debug mode seems to help, but I don't think this is the non-plus-ultra solution.

My workaround was to restructure the entire program and only call CPLEX a few times at the end of my search process now.